# Updating Specific Column of Last 20 Rows in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm using PHP, and MySQL. What I'm  trying to do is create a query to insert a new value into a column called "counter" starting from the second row all the way for 20 columns. The table needs to be sorted by 'article_id' in order to ensure that all the proper rows are updated.

If you can help me to do it for the 2nd row, I can apply that code to the other ones. So I only need the query to update one column at a time.

Table Structure: [image: Table Structure]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Better show us the table structure & what you have done ?

Comment: If you can help me to do it for the 2nd row, I can apply that code to the other ones. So I only need the query to update one column at a time.

Comment: how about showing your table structure ?

Comment: I added the image of the table from MySQL. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Vimzy image is the wrong way. better provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand it, you are trying to do something like this:

```
SET @id = SELECT `article_id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `article_id` ASC LIMIT 1, 1;
UPDATE `table` SET `counter` = 1 WHERE `article_id` > @id ORDER BY `article_id` LIMIT 20;
```

Where of course `table` is your table name.